# Spring Security and RequestCache with Anonymous User

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

That's my Security Configuration

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
            .requestCache().requestCache(new CustomRequestCache())
            .and().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().hasAnyAuthority(Role.getAllRoles())
            .and().formLogin().loginPage(LOGIN_URL).permitAll()
                  .loginProcessingUrl(LOGIN_PROCESSING_URL)
            .failureUrl(LOGIN_FAILURE_URL)
            .successHandler(new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
            .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl(LOGOUT_SUCCESS_URL);
}
```

The problem is that the CustomRequestCache is not called when I navigate from / to a protected URL and so the SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler does not redirect to the requested page after login.

I assume that this is because permitAll creates a anonymous user.

How do I have to configure Spring Security to make SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler work?

Comment: I tried recreating this, without the custom login/logout URLs, and it works for me.

I navigate to `/`, then I try navigating to `/test`, which redirects me to the login form. After logging in, I'm redirected to `/test`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting as an answer so I can include my code. I tried recreating your setup, this is my security configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String THE_AUTHORITY = "ROLE_ONE";

    @Override
    protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password(passwordEncoder().encode("user")).authorities(THE_AUTHORITY);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .requestCache().requestCache(new CustomRequestCache())
                .and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().hasAnyAuthority(THE_AUTHORITY)
                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                    .failureUrl("/")
                .successHandler(new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
                .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

and my controller

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String getTest() {
        return "You did it!";
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String getRoot() {
        return "<a href=/test>Go to test</a>";
    }

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String getLogin() {
        return "<form action=/login method=POST><input name=username /><input name=password /><input type=submit /></form>";
    }
}
```

I can open it, navigate to `/`, click the link to `/test` at which point I'm redirected to the login form. After logging in, I'm redirected to `/test`.

This is my CustomReuqestCache:

```
public class CustomRequestCache extends HttpSessionRequestCache {
    @Override
    public void saveRequest(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {
        System.out.println("Saving request to " + httpServletRequest.getRequestURI());
        super.saveRequest(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
    }

    @Override
    public HttpServletRequest getMatchingRequest(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {
         System.out.println("Returning request for " + httpServletRequest.getRequestURI());
         return super.getMatchingRequest(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your example, and indeed this works! So there must be another problem because the saveRequest method in my case is not called after htting / for the first time.

Comment: I found the error. The web framework I'm using is intercepting the request so the CustomRequestCache is not used. Thanks for your help

Comment: Glad you figured out it out!